# Number of elements of a set via action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group, acting on a finite set $X$. Burnside's lemma says that the following holds
$$|X/G| = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|St(g)|$$
I'm wondering does it mean that $|X| = |X/G|\cdot|G|$ as in Lagrange's theorem for groups. Or maybe there's a classification of actions for which this is true.

Comment: Your "$St$" reminds of "stabilizer", but then Burnside's lemma would read $|X/G|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in X}|St(x)|$. What you call $St(g)$ is not a subgroup of $G$ (as stabilizers are), and it is usually denoted with $X^g$ or $\operatorname{Fix}(g)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I am assuming that $X$ and $G$ are finite for everything to make sense.

Note that precisely by Burnside's lemma, your question translates to asking wether

$$
|X| = \sum_{g \in G}|X^g|
$$

where $X^g := \{x \in X : g \cdot x = x\}$.

However, when $g = 1$ we have

$$
X^1 = \{x \in X : 1 \cdot x = x\} = X
$$

so in turn this would mean that

$$
0 = \sum_{g \neq 1}|X^g|,
$$

or equivalently, that $|X^g| = 0$ for all $g \neq 1$.

Thus equality holds when $g \cdot x \neq x $ for all $x \in X, g \neq 1$. If I recall correctly, this is the definition of a *free action.*